# How to template a relationship field with multiple relations

Tags: safecracker, relationships, zoo-visitor

I'm trying to build a channel form for updating channel entry data. In this scenario, I'm relating a farmer to multiple butchers.

```
{exp:zoo_visitor:update_form}
    ...
    <ul id="slaughterhouses">
        <li class="selected">
            <label>{f_butchers:title}</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="f_butchers[data][]" value="{f_butchers:entry_id}" checked/>
        </li>
    </ul>
    ...
{/exp:zoo_visitor:update_form}
```

This entry currently has 2 selected butcher entries selected. But only one is rendered on the template. **I've tried wrapping the `<li>` element in `{f_butchers}` pair tags to no avail.**

In fact, wrapping them in `f_butcher` pair tags breaks the template parser and I get `{f_butchers:title}` instead of the actual butcher title. But once I wrap those pair tags in the `{exp:zoo_visitor:details}` pair tag, I get the one entry again. Still doesn't output the second entry.

The default `{field:f_butchers}` won't be enough since I need to do custom styling.

Does anyone know how to correctly template this field data?

Answer (score 0):

... broheim, you have to use relationships as a variable **pair** to loop over it, otherwise it just outputs one entry:

```
{exp:zoo_visitor:update_form}
    ...
    <ul id="slaughterhouses">
        {f_butchers}
        <li class="selected">
            <label>{f_butchers:title}</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="f_butchers[data][]" value="    {f_butchers:entry_id}" checked/>
        </li>
        {/f_butchers}
    </ul>
    ...
{/exp:zoo_visitor:update_form}
```

**Edit**

Ok... stupid question, but are you sure both relationship entries have a status that is displayable, IE, status = **Open** ?

Comment: I did that. Same exact output. One entry instead of two.

Comment: Okay: both entries are status=open. And both butchers are associated with the entry (confirmed from the control panel).